# How to scroll MULTIPLE scrollbars at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I scroll the wrapper div the 2 images should also scroll together with it but it seems only the 2 images sync together but not the wrapper

The 2 images should sync with the body's scrollbar

```js
$(function(){

    $('.linked').scroll(function(){
        $('.linked').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());    
    })

})
```

```css
#left { width: 300px; height: 400px; overflow: scroll; float: left; }
#right { width: 300px; height: 400px; overflow: scroll; float: left; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="left" class="linked">
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Eiffel_Tower_(72_names).jpg">
</div>
<div id="right" class="linked">
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Eiffel_Tower_(72_names).jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your goal is not clear. Be more specific about the desired behavior.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g8Krz/510/
What I want is for the 2 images to scroll together with the body

Comment: If you want the two images scroll together, you shouldn't add scroll bars in the two images, just add into the container div.

Comment: but is it possible?

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/romgrk/stpdxLwn/11/
As Shawn Xiao said, you can use a CSS background image for that

Comment: @RomGrk your JS Fiddle code example does not work. Only the window scrolls but the two divs inside do not when trying to scroll them directly.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly you're question is how to sync a set of scroll bars including the window scroll bar? This is possible and I will demonstrate for education purposes only however this is not something I would personally recommend.

Manipulating the browser window scroll bar can create a poor user experience as it interferes with the expected behavior of the scroll bar. Additionally, scrollbar manipulation can cause unexpected behavior and may not work consistently across different browsers and devices, leading to a fragmented user experience.

This example does not take into consideration the dimensions of the browser window and elements with scroll bars so be warned that it might not work as expected.

```js
// Pseudo code
// 1. Query the scroll bars you want to sync
// 2. Add event listener to each of them
// 3. In the event listener, set the scroll position of the other scroll bar(s) to the same value

// Step 1
const scrollBarContainers = [
  ...document.querySelectorAll('.scrollable'),
  document // Include document for window scrolling
];

// Step 2
scrollBarContainers.forEach(container => {
  container.addEventListener('scroll', syncScrolls);
});

// Step 3
function syncScrolls(e) {
  scrollBarContainers.forEach(container => {
    if (container !== e.target) {
      // The document element doesn't directly have a scrollLeft property.
      // It's on the scrollingElement. The other elements have it directly.
      if (container.scrollingElement) {
        container.scrollingElement.scrollLeft = e.target.scrollLeft;
      } else if (e.target.scrollingElement) {
        container.scrollLeft = e.target.scrollingElement.scrollLeft;
      } else {
        container.scrollLeft = e.target.scrollLeft;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 900px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  overflow: auto;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container scrollable"><span></span></div>
<div class="container scrollable"><span></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
let l = document.getElementById(".left");
let r = document.getElementById(".right");

l.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  r.scrollTop = l.scrollTop;
});
l.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  r.scrollTop = l.scrollTop;
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.